# Android Studio gives error below when start emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

When I start Android Studio's native emulator (Nexus 5X API 28 x86) It gives error below:

---

[image]

---

> Event Log :
>   [image]

---

> Note : I run project with real device.Its working.

Hope you can help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to install HAXM manually as specified in [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/android-sdk-emulator/hardware-acceleration/) tutorial

Comment: I installed HAXM now app runs correctly.But Android Studio does not see my Nox emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your HAXM installer. For me, it works.
[image: HAXM installer in android sdk tools]

Comment: I did it and Android's native emulator runs correctly.But Android Studio still  does not see my Nox emulator.